# Value of $n$ in $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac {x^x}{(x!)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The expression $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac {x^x}{(x!)^n}$ $\to \infty$ for $n$ less than roughly $1.223$, and then afterwards converges towards $0$.  Is there some closed form expression for the value of $n$ at which the expression changes?

EDIT:
In this case, $x$ can be any real.  $x!$ refers to $\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: I guess $x$ is an integer and $n$ is not. Do you know Stirling's formula ?

Comment: @A.Bailleul $x$ does not have to be an integer if you interpret the factorial as a Gamma function. Let the OP clarify

Comment: @gt6989b: whether $x$ is an integer or not doesn't matter. It matters for $n$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: why it matters for $n$ to be integral or not ?

Comment: @GCab: what do you think of $1.223$ ?

Comment: How did you obtain the value $1.223$ ?

Comment: I typed the expression into desmos and then used a slider for $n$.  At $n=1.223$ It stopped converging to $\infty$ and went to $0$ instead

Comment: @WilliamGrannis: this was not a reliable way to observe convergence.

Comment: I agree, but it is a reliable way to find cool stuff.

Comment: @w: ok if you call cool wrong properties...

Answer (score 2):

$$\log\frac{x^x}{\left(\dfrac xe\right)^{nx}}=(1-n)x\log x+nx$$ tends to $\pm\infty$ depending on the sign of $1-n$. There is no *mystery constant*.

Comment: How does this answer my question?  Show some more steps.  What relation does $\log\frac{x^x}{\left(\dfrac xe\right)^{nx}}$ have to my original question?

Comment: @WilliamGrannis: Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask Desmos (which the OP, in a comment, indicated he was experimenting with) to graph the function $x\ln x-n\ln(x!)$ for various of values of $n$ (e.g., $n=1.2$ and $n=1.3$), you'll see that it stops drawing the graph at $x=169$. (At least that's what I found on the version I use.) Presumably it does so because it feels it cannot reliably compute $x!$ beyond that point.  For $n=1.2$, the graph I get indicates the maximum occurs at $x\approx145.386$ and thereafter the function is decreasing (and will eventually tend to $-\infty$), but the value is still a fairly large positive number (around $25.2$) at $x=169$.

The take-home lesson here is that sometimes graphing the *logarithm* of a function you're interested in can be more informative than graphing the function itself.

Comment: How can it go to negative infinity?  Both the numerator and denominator are positive.

Comment: @WilliamGrannis, I'm graphing the *logarithm* of your function.